# Read file in columns in C

Tags: c, file

So, I have a file like this:

```
12345 name1 18 500.000000
12345 name2 18 500.000000
```

And I wanted to read the file and each column go to a different variable. So I coded this:

```
void updateStruct() {
    char c;
    int lines, i;
    accounts account[accMAX];
    FILE *acc = fopen("acc.dat", "r+");
    if (acc == NULL)
        return;
    for (c = getc(acc); c != EOF; c = getc(acc))
        if (c == '\n')
            lines += 1;
    fscanf(acc, "%d %s %d %f", &account[0].number, account[0].name,
                               &account[0].age, &account[0].balance);
}
```

Somehow, the `fscanf()` doesn't attribute any value to the variables. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop? Does it read the whole file till the EOF so fscanf has nothing to read?

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop leaves the file pointer at the end of the file. Call `rewind` to position the file pointer back at the start of the file before calling `fscanf`.

Comment: Hello! As you said, I add the rewind(acc) to my code. However, the code still doesn't work.`void updateStruct () {
 char c;
 int lines, i;
 accounts account[accMAX];
 FILE *acc = fopen("acc.dat", "r+");
 if (acc == NULL) return;
 for (c = getc(acc); c != EOF; c = getc(acc)) if (c == '\n') lines += 1;
 rewind(acc);
 fscanf(acc, "%d %s %d %f", &account[0].number, account[0].name, &account[0].age, &account[0].balance);
}`

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop to compute the number of lines reads the whole file. `fscanf()` fails to convert anything and returns `EOF`.

You must rewind the position to the beginning of file with `rewind(acc)` or `fseek(acc, 0L, SEEK_SET)`.

Note also that variable `c` must have type `int` for the `EOF` test to function correctly. Furthermore you should also count the last line that may or may not have a newline.

Here is a modified version:

```
accounts *updateStruct(int *countp) {
    int c, last, lines, i;
    FILE *acc = fopen("acc.dat", "r");
    if (acc == NULL)
        return NULL;
    last = EOF;
    while ((c = getc(acc)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            lines += 1;
        last = c;
    }
    if (last != '\n') { // last line did not have a newline
        lines += 1;
    }
    rewind(acc);

    accounts *account = calloc(lines, sizeof(account));
    if (account == NULL) {
        fclose(acc);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count;) {
        if (fscanf(acc, "%d %s %d %f", &account[i].number, account[i].name,
                                       &account[i].age, &account[i].balance) != 4) {
            // invalid line: skip to the newline
            while ((c = getc(acc)) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(acc);
    *countp = i;
    return account;
}
```